# open api.yml generate java class file , field returning an additional json key

Tags: java, maven, swagger

I have created an api.yml file and generated them using openapi maven plugin my yml file consist of this

```
 manager:
        ...other fields
          type: object
          properties:
            value:
              type: string
            $ref:
              type: string
            name:
              type: string
```

It created a java file for me
with variables with @JsonProperty being annotated on the variables

```
private String value;
private String $ref
private String name

// getter setters

for $ref , it created 

    public String get$Ref() { return this.$ref }
    public String set$Ref(String $ref) { return this.$ref = $ref }
```

when i call my api endpoint to test

it gave me an additonal key which is

```
{
  value:'1'
  $Ref: "Reference"
  name: "test"
  $ref : "Reference"
}
```

im suspecting that the setter function is causing this issue as it is in capital 'R' but i can't change that java file as it is generated via the api.yml

if there is any idea on how i can remove that $Ref.

edit* adding link for the generator i used

https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/tree/master/modules/openapi-generator-maven-plugin

Comment: Which generator are you using in the plugin? Because I can't remember having used a generator that doesn't add an `@JsonProperty("$ref")` annotation.

Comment: I used openapi-generator-maven-plugin
Ya my bad I didn't add it in my sample code cause was writing it manually here, 
it did add a @JsonProperty("$ref")

Comment: It was not the question which plugin you used. Which generator do you use `java`, `spring`, `kotlin` etc. ?

Comment: Java, https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/tree/master/modules/openapi-generator-maven-plugin

Comment: That would mean that https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/modules/openapi-generator/src/main/resources/Java/pojo.mustache and https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/modules/openapi-generator/src/main/resources/Java/jackson_annotations.mustache are used. These include `@JsonProperty(JSON_PROPERTY_{{nameInSnakeCase}})`. This is apparently not the same as from https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/modules/openapi-generator/src/main/resources/JavaJaxRS/spec/pojo.mustache which uses `@JsonProperty("{{baseName}}")`.

Comment: Actually it is; it uses `public static final String JSON_PROPERTY_{{nameInSnakeCase}} = "{{baseName}}";` which is the same. However, it appears that Gson is used by default: https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/modules/openapi-generator/src/main/resources/Java/JSON.mustache explicitly uses it. The POJO mustache file does include `@SerializedName(SERIALIZED_NAME_{{nameInSnakeCase}})` and `public static final String SERIALIZED_NAME_{{nameInSnakeCase}} = "{{baseName}}";`. Which JSON libraries are part of your dependencies?